# deploying Django project to AWS elasticbeanstack getting ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Every time i run eb deploy, it is a success but when i run eb open, i get internal server error 500. I have tried to go use answers to similar problems in this platform but am notyet able to fix the problem.

this is from my logs

```
ile "/opt/python/current/app/xxx/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
mod_wsgi (pid=7546): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/xxx/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=7546): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/xxx/wsgi.py'.
```

kindly assist

this is my **wsgi.py** file
    import os, sys

```
sys.path = ['/var/www/xxx'] + sys.path

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxx.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: wsgi python compiled matches python/django version? use virtual env?. Anyway try add the `site-packages` directory into `sys.path`.

Comment: i am using virtual env, python 2.7 and django 1.9.2 @JavierClavero

Comment: @JavierClavero i do not know how to add site-packages to sys.path kindly show me how its done.

Comment: add to `wsgi.py` `sys.path.append('<path virtual env>/lib/<other directories>/site-packages')` and try. If  don't  work provide more information how OS version where you deploy or `.conf`, will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 deploying to AWS elasticbeanstalk